# useEffect isn't working though rendering happened

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying "fetchPostData" using useEffect.
It should work when rendered, but it isn't working.
callPostUrl, callComments have no problem because when I used fetchPostData without useEffect, it returned correct data through it was in the infinite loop.

I consoled logged "fetchPostData pre" to double check whether callPostUrl, callComments function are proper or not, but nothing in console.

fetchPostData isn't working when I rendered the page.
It is not being executed.
Can not understand why.
Please help me.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { PageHeader } from "../components";
import { Card, BlankComment, PostCommentBox, CommentBox } from "../components";
import Menu from "../css/icon/Menu.svg";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { callPostUrl, callComments } from "../api/post";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background-color: #f0f0f6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;
function PostViewPage() {
  const { postId } = useParams();
  const [comments, setComments] = useState({});
  const [post, setPost] = useState("");

  const [noComment, setNoComment] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("setNoComment");
    setNoComment(true);
  }, [noComment]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPostData = async () => {
      console.log("fetchPostData pre");
      const postData = await callPostUrl(postId);
      const commentsData = await callComments(postId);
      setPost(postData);
      setComments(commentsData);
    };
    fetchPostData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <PageHeader
        pageTitle="게시글"
        rightButton={<img src={Menu} alt="img" />}
      />
      <Card key={postId} type={"full"} post={post} />
      {noComment ? <BlankComment /> : <CommentBox comments={comments} />}
      <PostCommentBox />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default PostViewPage;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "isn't working"? What happens, what doesn't?

Comment: Oh I edited my text. fetchPostData is not being executed at all. Nothing in console. Just blank.

Answer (score -1):

You are in the right directions but result are returning as promise.

Please try with below code sample

```
await callPostUrl(postId).then((postdata) => setPost(postData));
await callComments(postId).then((commentsData) => setComments(commentsData));
```

Comment: This is effectively equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still, fetchPostData isn't being executed. :(